# Image hyperlink dimensions wrong

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink to an image and it works fine, but when I hover over the `<A>...</A>` node in Chrome Dev Tools, it shows the wrong dimensions.

Dev Tools shows that the dimensions are 512x18 and it also shows the box model is nudged below the image by about 5 pixels or so.

I don't understand why this is happening or what is going on here. If I have a 512x512 pixel image, I want the hyperlink dimensions to be 512x512 pixels.

[image: Image hyperlink dimensions wrong]

```html
<A HREF="https://via.placeholder.com/512"><IMG ALT="Text" SRC="https://via.placeholder.com/512"/></A>
```

I tried adding `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` attributes to the image, but that didn't work. It seemed like the only way to get it to work was to add a defined CSS size to the surrounding `<A>...</A>` hyperlink element.

```
STYLE="display: inline-block; width: 512px; height: 512px"
```

Is there any other way of doing this without having to hardcode the dimensions of the image?

Comment: just display: inline-block will be fine, no need to add width and height.

Comment: If I just add `display: inline-block`, the dimensions are not 512x512 pixels. They show up as 512x521 pixels, too tall by 9 pixels.

Comment: ok then add another rule line-height: 0 to anchor tag, its becuase of line-height you are getting height more than what you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "display: inline-flex;" on the anchor tag, you will get same dimensions of the image for anchor tag. I have added it inline in below snippet but you can move this property to your CSS file :

```
<A HREF="https://via.placeholder.com/512" style="display:inline-flex;"><IMG ALT="Text" SRC="https://via.placeholder.com/512"/></A>
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this should be how the native `inline` display would work for images, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Making img tag to block and anchor tag to inline-block also makes both height to 512pixels